# Tab character width in Terminal

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal

Default tab width for Mac OS X Terminal.app is 8. I want to change it to 2. How can I do it?

I've found [tabs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tabs.1.html) command, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: Link above now at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tabs.1.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To set your tab with to 2 spaces, use this command in the Terminal App:

```
tabs -2
```

Replace `2` with your desired width in spaces.

View the full [manual for tabs](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tabs.1.html) to learn about all options.

Comment: I can't get `tabs` command to work properly. If I try `echo $'12345678|\n\t|'` on a new Terminal, I can see the default 8 tab width working correctly. But if I try `tabs -4; echo $'1234|\n\t|'` I get misaligned pipe symbols. Is this a bug in Terminal?

Comment: Works as expected for me with correct alignment.  What is your terminal windows size, what version of OSX are you on and what font (and font size) are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach, for use on an ad-hoc basis:

```
my_command_that_outputs_tabs | expand -t 2
```

`expand` is a POSIX standard util and should be available anywhere.

Note that this utility *converts* tabs into spaces, so you should be careful if you're planning to redirect the output anywhere after you've inspected it on the terminal.